# Unable to SSH over WiFi, working when connected via LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh, raspberry-pi

I am trying to SSH into my Raspberry Pi 3 via my Win10 PC both connected to my router via WiFi.

What I did was that I assigned a static IP from my router's config page to both my PC and my Raspberry Pi, and the as I tried SSHing into my Pi using the IP I assigned, puTTY just kept reporting.

> Session timed out.

While trying to ping via command prompt-

> Destination host unreachable.

However no packet loss is reported.

Anyways, what I noticed, is that if I connect my PC to the router via a LAN cable, the sshing works fine, I can ssh into my PI without any problems.
I even tried sshing using my external IP, I was able to ping it but puTTY reported

> Software closed connection.

Now the thing is wiring my laptop to my router in order to ssh into my Pi is a bit restricting, also I would like to ssh into the Pi via other devices, My Lumia 525 for instance, and I can't plug a LAN cable into that.
This is network issue I think.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks!

**EDIT :**
Interestingly, ipconfig tells that while connected via LAN my IPv4 address isn't actually the one I set for my PC. But when I connect via WiFi, the correct IP shows up. Subnet is the same.
This network is really getting confusing now.

Comment: I think you should review your static IPs. Seems that there are not on the same network/subnet or your PC network is not configured properly.

Comment: @NIZ they most probably are... Atleast that's what both my computer and my Pi tells me. Any way you could suggest I can confirm this?

Comment: I think you mess up the MAC address for binding. The MAC of the LAN is not the same as the mac of the WIFI. Please paste the output of ipconfig and ifconfig on both devices with the problematic settup.

Comment: @Niz what do I do then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What router do you have?
I would try to check your router configuration under Wifi for Network Segregation.
Can you ping from your laptop via WIFI to your phone for instance?

*Edit* meant AP Isolation, sorry was on the right menu, wrong term. Network Segregation is used to separate different networks, one Wifi from another, or Wifi from cable

Comment: Turns on, most probably AP Isolation being on was causing the problems. Disabled it but still no effect. And no, I can't ping my phone from my laptop

Comment: Don't know about network segregation but AP Isolation being enabled on my router was the problem here. Many thanks!

Comment: Happy to help or inspire!